# Access DynamoDB VPC Endpoint from Lambda running inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc

I'm having difficulties accessing DynamoDB via VPC End point from my Lambda which is also running in the same VPC. I created a VPC End point for Dynamo and configured Route Table which is in the subnet (whose cidr block say 10.11.0.10/16).
My lambda Security group already have egress rule which will allow accessing that sunet. But still I'm getting timeout. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your exact security group and route table configuration (screenshot maybe)?

Comment: @jogold Thank you! I figured out the fix. I have added another security group rule to lambda with the following *egress: type* *prefix_list_id - dynamo vpc end point prefix list id*. Then it worked fine